# Django Test.py django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: books_book.id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

when I run `python manage.py tests`

I get this error as `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: books_book.id`

it causes most of the other tests to fail

Here are the full `tests.py` file:

```
 class BookViewTests(TestCase):
        self.user=get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='test',
            email='test@gmail.com',
            city='city',
            state='state',
            password='secret',
            id_2 ='96540845',
            work = 'Wipro'
            )
      
        self.book =Book.objects.create(
            title='How to Win Friends and Influence People',
            author='Dale Carnegie',
            genre ='Self-help',
            owner =self.user,
            id ='75777553',
            is_approved=False,
            available=False
        )
    #book detail view
    def test_book_detail_view(self):
        self.client.login(username='test',password='secret')
        resp =self.client.get(reverse('book_detail',kwargs={'book_id':75777553}))
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code,200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(resp,'book_detail.html')
```

This is my model

`My model`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id=models.SlugField(max_length=8,primary_key=True)
    genre_choices=[(i,i) for i in ['Biography','Business','Children','Classic','Comedy','Fantasy','History','Horror','Mystery','Mythology','Poetry','Religion','Romance','SciFi','Self-Help','Spirituality','Thriller','Non-Fiction','Fiction','Others']]
    title =models.CharField(max_length =255)
    author =models.CharField(max_length =255,validators=[alphabet_validate])
    genre =models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=genre_choices)
    available =models.BooleanField(default =True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Slug', null=True,blank=True,max_length = 200)
```

How to solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check your database if you have this id `75777553` already present...

Comment: Yes I have checked the database this id is not present.

Comment: This error came after adding this  slug field  :  
 `slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Slug', null=True,blank=True,max_length = 200)`